# Resize Vertical Tick Label Height (XYStepChart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I've got the following chart made with JFreeChart:
[image]

Is it possible (and if it is how) to extend the dates on the x-axis so that they contain the year, eg. 4-II-2010, 5-II-2010, ..., 6-III-2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how you are formatting the dates now, but [`setDateFormatOverride`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride%28java.text.DateFormat%29) in [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) allows you to specify a suitable [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). If not already available, you should be able to override [`getShortMonths()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getShortMonths%28%29) in [`DateFormatSymbols`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) for the Roman numerals.

Addendum: For correct localization, it may be easier to do something like this:

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(); // default locale
String[] roman = { ... };
dfs.setShortMonths(roman);
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", dfs));
```

Comment: Hay, thank you very much!
It really worked. This way I have full control on the date format shown on the x-axis.