# Display days in TimeSeriesChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, days, timeserieschart

How can I display the names of the days ("Sunday, Monday....") on the time axis, instead of just the date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setDateFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride%28java.text.DateFormat%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723103).

Addendum:

> isn't there a way to change only the top level?

[`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) has methods related to the zoom state. You should be able to set the date format as desired either by overriding the `chartChanged()` method or in response to user input, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575).

Comment: After using `setDateFormatOverride()` the axis is always labeled after the SimpleDateFormat i gave it, on every zoom level ; isn´t there a way to change only the top level ? In other words, top level "EEE, dd.MM.yyyy" and further down "HH:mm".

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
DateAxis xAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
xAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(
      DateTickUnit.DAY,
      1,
      new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.DE)));
```

Comment: This is a good alternative, but `Locale.getDefault()` might be less locale specific.

Comment: @trashgod: May may not, This strongly depends on our use case. `Local.getDefault()` works in a stand alone appliction, but not on a server. -- Anyway: you are correct in standalone application.