# Jfreechart DateAxis should show date on the top of first tick unit

Tags: jfreechart

can anyone help me how I could display the date alone on top of the first tick unit of DateAxis in Jfreechart Gantt

Like this:

6july|||7july|||8july|||

valueAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnit.HOUR,6));
 ///what needs to be extended here to get the desired format as said above
valueAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("'|'d,MMM"));

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because a Gantt chart uses a `DateAxis` for the range, you can invoke [`setDateFormatOverride()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html#setDateFormatOverride%28java.text.DateFormat%29), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723103). Of course you'll want to use `getRangeAxis()`.

Addendum: Reading more closely, you can use `setLowerMargin()` and/or `setUpperMargin()` on the range axis to leave some room for the date over the end ticks.

Comment: Thank you for the response.But I would like this :lets say if I have valueAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnit.HOUR,6));only the first tick out of four ticks on the rangeAxis should display the date and remaining three ticks blank ;6/7 |  |   |  7/7| | |8/7| | |     Thanks

Comment: Ah, you want the intervening ticks to have no label. AFAIK, that's not supported.