# Step chart for Perl (not chartdirector)

Tags: perl, charts, plot

Is there a free (preferabbly Open Source) Perl module that generates Step charts like the XYStep chart of [JFreeChart here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721536/resize-vertical-tick-label-height-xystepchart)? I know ChartDirector for Perl does this, but any other module?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Chart::Clicker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Chart%3a%3aClicker) on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org)

Comment: chromatic has a nice writeup on Chart::Clicker on his Modern Perl blog recently

Comment: and [here's the link](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2012/02/easy-and-attractive-graphs-with-chartclicker.html)