# Gantt Chart in jfreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a .csv file containing TaskId and TaskStartTimerValue. I want to make a Gantt Graph displaying TaskId on the x axis and TaskStartTimervalue at the y axis. I am using a demo from this link [this link at sanjaal.com](http://sanjaal.com/java/343/charts-in-java/creating-gantt-chart-in-java-using-jfreechart-api-exampletutorial/).

The demo uses a *SimpleTimePeriod* method to get the timing range. 
Is there any other method available that I can use to pass my timer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `TimePeriod`, you can use the [`Task`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/gantt/Task.html#Task%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date%29) constructor that accepts two `Date` instances:

```
public Task(java.lang.String description,
    java.util.Date start,
    java.util.Date end)
```

Use an instance of `Calendar` to create your dates. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949913/230513), there are two main tasks:

```
Task t1 = new Task("Design", date(1, MAY), date(31, MAY));
Task t2 = new Task("Proposal", date(1, JUNE), date(31, JUNE));
```

This simple auxiliary method, analogous to the example's `makeDate()`, generates dates for a fixed year:

```
private static Date date(final int day, final int month) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2012, month, day);
    final Date result = calendar.getTime();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help,Can you please suggest me how can I display our actual timer values. when I did it above way the timer values get converted to "Date"format,I do not want timer values in Date format.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you mean you want to change the format of the axis labels?

Comment: yeah...I want whatever value I passed to Task, graph axis should display that actual value without converting it into "Date" format.

Comment: You can use `setDateFormatOverride()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2723103/230513).