# How to internationalize the date value in jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can any one please tell how to internationalize the date value in jfreechart like (30 Jun 2013 to 30 junio 2013).

Thanks.

Comment: What's your default `Locale`? Did you specify a suitable `Locale` in your `DateFormat`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) is not your default `Locale`, you can specify it explicitly from among the [*Supported Locales*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html):

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("es", "ES")));
```

Tested in [`TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html), [included](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html) in the distribution. See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723103/230513) regarding `DateFormatSymbols`.

Comment: Thanks dude. But my req is something different.

Comment: See thie example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartTimePeriodValuesDemo2.htm . I want to show the Russian lang. How to do this one?

Comment: Hello trash, Thanks for your above tip. It solves my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To change only the language (and keep dynamic format from JFreechart) use `setLocale` instead of `setDateFormatOverride` :

```
            DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
            axis.setLocale(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```