# how to create a xychart with 2 date axis by JFreechart?

Tags: java, date, jfreechart

I have 2 group of data(date format),and I want to use one of them to be the X-axis and another to be the Y-axis,could jfreechart do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes simply use a xyseries or TimSeriesCollection

Have a look at this example

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYLogAxesDemo.htm

or

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18492368/230513) also uses a `DateAxis` for the Y-axis.