# JfreeChart: dynamic Date time values into XY chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JfreeChart to create dynamic charts. Currently, am facing a problem to create a Chart to show dynamic Date time values from database.

[image]

Showing above picture, I want to fix Y axis with months JAN to Dec.

Since long back trying , but I could not find any solution. Please give me the solution to fix above issue

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html), like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723103/261156), and format the labels for months.

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Catalina Island

Comment: But, I want to fix Y axis always JAN to DEC as label names..and want to show dynamic data values on X axis. 

Example: Oct 3rd 2014 value getting from database..I want to show the value in chart in above image as I mentioned.